# How do I use icons on a TreeItem in a VSCode extension when using webpack

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have troubles adding icons to a `TreeItem` in my VSCode extension. When I load the extension, [the item has a blank space where the icon ought to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AR72.png).

I have tried to mimic the `nodeDependency` [example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample). I have the following in `extension.ts`:

```ts
class Foo extends TreeItem {
  iconPath = {
    light: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'light', 'icon.svg'),
    dark: path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'icon.svg')
  };
...
}
```

For context, part of my directory contents is

```
src
  extension.ts
resources
  dark
    icon.svg
  light
    icon.svg
dist
  extension.js
  extension.js.map
```

So I am trying to dot out of `dist/extension.js` and find the appropriate svg-file.

I use webpack to bundle the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack changes `__filename`, so your attempt to go to the resource directory fails.

Add the following to `webpack.config.js` to leave `__filename` unchanged:

```js
module.exports = {
  [...]
  node: {
    __filename: false
  }
};
```